# tableView not refreshing after it should have refreshed (called by separate class) - swift

Tags: swift, database, uitableview, class, persistent

[image]

Here is an ugly representation of my layout. I have a tableView in a ViewController and when the side button of a cell is selected, the grey view emerges with the name of the cell and a delete button. I have set up an algorithm when the delete button is selected, to remove the key of the dictionary (in this case 'cell five'). However, do to the separate classes both subviews are running on, I am having trouble reloading the tableview directly after the key is removed.

The closest I have currently gotten is this code after the entry is removed:

```
let controller = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tableVC")
controller.viewDidLoad()
```

This obviously runs the viewDidLoad() function on the other class without causing any fatal errors such as 'unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional value' (meaning that the tableView was not recognized).

For extra testing, I have tried printing texts in the viewDidLoad, which does print in addition to the cellForRowAt override function and printing each entry, which still unfortunately included the one I was trying to remove!

I am sure that my removing algorithm is functioning properly as I run an IDENTICAL code for the viewWillAppear override function, which only returns what I want.

One important detail about my code:

I the way I am updating this data is with a permanent file saved to remember each entry and change (so when I run the viewDidLoad, I basically re-read the changed file).

Would anyone have any suggestions on what my cause the error or any suggestions to solve my problem? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Why not apply a protocol to implement this?
Something similar to this:

Your ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class HomeController: UIViewController,TableRowDeleteProtocol{

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    deletePopUp.delegate = self // set this to get the reference of the HomeController in your custom view.
    //Move whatever you code you have here to refresh your TableView away from here

    refreshTable()
}

func refreshTable(){
    //Fetch data and reload the TableView
}

func deleteTableViewRow() {
    //delete the data from your saved file or make any change to the datasource
    refreshTable()
}


}


protocol TableRowDeleteProtocol {
func deleteTableViewRow()
}
```

In your custom view where you are confirming the delete operation, do something as below:

```
import UIKit

class DeletePopUpView: UIView{

var delegate: TableRowDeleteProtocol?

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)


}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

@IBAction func confirmDelete(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate?.deleteTableViewRow() 
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but when I apply a protocol and call tableView.reloadData() in my delegate function, it throws me a fatal error  "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional value." Would you perhaps know how to avoid this issue?

Comment: I will share the code in a moment, just one question first: Why are you calling the 'override init (etc)'? It seems to me that this code is redundant, especially because you are not setting up anything in it.

Comment: Unfortunately I have not gotten the type of delegate you are setting up to work quite properly (so that it executes the function) and was rather a protocol set up differently, which executed the function, but gave me the nil error (which was also the case when just doing `HomeController.deleteTableViewRow`)

Comment: The UIView class I showed to you there is a just a UIView with some initiation methods for you to fill up with codes according to your need. Whats the problem that you are facing with the protocol? And you still haven't told me what was which var was nil.

Comment: The variable which was nil was the view controller. When calling the protocol function, it apparently does not read my @IBOutlet connecting my tableView at the beginning of the class, meaning that my tableView is undefined.

Comment: Well, your tableView is defined, else you won't even get the values in the Table View.

When you created the view, did you set the delegate as an instance of the view controller?